# Easiest way to parse semi-structured text file

Tags: import, parsing

I have [a plain text file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25202446/data.txt) with some data. I need two things:

1. Be able to **extract certain values** for the various field, e.g. to extract the 'Mean Dose [%]', that is to extract number `103.3`, and
2. Get **a list of lists** with the numbers after the line containing `'Relative Dose [%]'`, e.g. `{0.5, 22.5, 0}, ... }`.

**Note**: The data files are generated from another program, so their format is always the same. No need to take measures to be robust while parsing to cover edge cases.

Normally:

1. I would write an ad-hoc program in *C* to get the data I'm interested in. How do you approach such parsing problems with *Mathematica*?

For example is there a command that searches in a list of tuples for a string as the 1st element returning the 2nd element ? Like (pseudocode):

```
dat = Import["~/myfile"];
dat[["Mean Dose [%]"]]
(* returns 103.3 *)
```

2. I would probably edit the files manually removing all text including the `Relative Dose [%]'` and then import the rest similar to CSV files or so.

Here follows a part of the data file:

```
Patient Name         : XXXXX, XXXXX (XXXX/XX), ()
Patient ID           : XXXX/XX
Comment              : DVHs for one plan
Date                 : 19.09.2014  13:53:00
Type                 : Differential Dose Volume Histogram
Description          : The differential DVH displays the share of the total
                       volume in structures receiving a given dose as
                       a function of equivalent dose intervals. In the data,
                       below, dose values correspond to the center of the
                       dose interval.

Plan: 3FIF ST
Prescribed dose [cGy]: 4500.0
% for dose (%): 100.0

Structure: PTV
Approval Status: Approved
Plan: 3FIF ST
Course: C1
Volume [cm³]: 370.8
Dose Cover.[%]: 100.0
Sampling Cover.[%]: 100.0
Min Dose [%]: 89.7
Max Dose [%]: 108.3
Mean Dose [%]: 103.3
Modal Dose [%]: 107.2
Median Dose [%]: 103.6
STD [%]: 2.9
Equiv. Sphere Diam. [cm]: N/A
Conformity Index: N/A
Gradient Measure [cm]: N/A

Relative dose [%]          Dose [cGy] dVolume / dDose [cm³ / %]
              0.5                22.5                         0
              1.5                67.5                         0
              2.5               112.5                         0
              3.5               157.5                         0
              4.5               202.5                         0
              5.5               247.5                         0
              6.5               292.5                         0
              7.5               337.5                         0
              8.5               382.5                         0
              9.5               427.5                         0
             10.5               472.5                         0
             11.5               517.5                         0
             12.5               562.5                         0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first case, one way will be to read the entire file as a `String` and manipulate it e.g:

```
txt = ReadList["dose.txt", String];
```

Then do something like:

```
Flatten @ StringCases[txt, "Mean Dose [%]: " ~~ (x : NumberString) -> ToExpression @ x]
```

> {103.3}

I guess you can turn it into a function:

```
sValues[s_String] := Flatten @ StringCases[txt, s ~~ (x : NumberString) :> ToExpression @ x]
```

Then:

```
sValues["Mean Dose [%]: "]
```

> {103.3}

```
sValues["Max Dose [%]: "]
```

> {108.3}

And so on...

For the second case, if you know the number of lines you want to skip until you get to the data then the following should work fine:

```
readFile[file_String?FileExistsQ, n_Integer] := Module[{str = OpenRead[file], data},
  Skip[str, String, n];
  data = ReadList[str, Table[Number, {3}]];
  Close[str];
  data
 ]
```

Use:

```
readFile["dose.txt", 30]
```

> ```
> {{0.5, 22.5, 0}, {1.5, 67.5, 0}, {2.5, 112.5, 0}, {3.5, 157.5, 0}, 
>  {4.5, 202.5, 0}, {5.5, 247.5, 0}, {6.5, 292.5, 0}, {7.5, 337.5, 0}, 
>  {8.5, 382.5, 0}, {9.5, 427.5, 0}, {10.5, 472.5, 0}, {11.5, 517.5, 0}, {12.5, 562.5, 0}}
> ```

Another possibility for the second case:

```
StringSplit[Flatten @ StringCases[txt, Repeated[Whitespace ~~ NumberString, {3}]],
            Whitespace] // ToExpression
```

> ```
> {{0.5, 22.5, 0}, {1.5, 67.5, 0}, {2.5, 112.5, 0}, {3.5, 157.5, 0}, 
>  {4.5, 202.5, 0}, {5.5, 247.5, 0}, {6.5, 292.5, 0}, {7.5, 337.5, 0},  
>  {8.5, 382.5, 0}, {9.5, 427.5, 0}, {10.5, 472.5, 0}, {11.5, 517.5, 0}, {12.5, 562.5, 0}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks @RunnyKine! I suppose I can extract the values I'm interested in and then chop all first _N_ lines to parse the columns.

Comment: @Zet, yes you can. But I may add something to my answer for the second part soon.

Comment: @Zet. Thanks for the accept, see my update.